# php show data in 3 columns

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to show all fields in each columns, but, of course, I have a lot of different ID.
something like this:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3

id1       id4       id7
id2       id5       id8
id3       id6       id9
```

I wrote a code in php and I get results from mysql database in one column. 
I'd like to divide results in three columns, but I don't know how I can do it. 
I know that PDO is better to connect to database, but I don't know it (I will study it soon) and I need to use this code now.

This is my code:

```
    <?php

  include 'config.php';
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM immobili"; //WHERE citta='pincopalla'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
  if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $id = stripslashes($fetch['id']);
      $riferimenti = stripslashes($fetch['riferimenti']);
      $titolo = stripslashes($fetch['titolo']);
      $tipotransazione = stripslashes($fetch['tipotransazione']);
      $tipoproprieta = stripslashes($fetch['tipoproprieta']);
      $regione = stripslashes($fetch['regione']);
      $citta = stripslashes($fetch['citta']);
      $prezzo = stripslashes($fetch['prezzo']);
      $spazivivibili = stripslashes($fetch['spazivivibili']);
      $terrenoprivato = stripslashes($fetch['terrenoprivato']);
      $condizioniproprieta = stripslashes($fetch['condizioniproprieta']);
      $piano = stripslashes($fetch['piano']);
      $numeropiani = stripslashes($fetch['numeropiani']);
      $numerostanze = stripslashes($fetch['numerostanze']);
      $numerocamereletto = stripslashes($fetch['numerocamereletto']);
      $numerobagni = stripslashes($fetch['numerobagni']);
      $numeroantibagni = stripslashes($fetch['numeroantibagni']);
      $tipologiariscaldamento = stripslashes($fetch['tipologiariscaldamento']);
      $cucina = stripslashes($fetch['cucina']);
      $ascensore = stripslashes($fetch['ascensore']);
      $postoauto = stripslashes($fetch['postoauto']);
      $balconeterrazzo = stripslashes($fetch['balconeterrazzo']);
      $ipe = stripslashes($fetch['ipe']);
      $classeenergetica = stripslashes($fetch['classeenergetica']);
      $spesecondominiali = stripslashes($fetch['spesecondominiali']);
      $comforts = stripslashes($fetch['comforts']);
      $linkvideo = stripslashes($fetch['linkvideo']);
  $descrizione = stripslashes($fetch['descrizione']);
      $data = date("d-m-Y", $fetch['str_data']);
      ?>
 <?php

 $dirname = "images/".$citta;
$images = $dirname.$linkvideo;

echo '<a href="#" class="lightbox"><img src="'.$images.'" /></a><br />';
echo '<div class="backdrop"></div><div class="box"><div class="close">x</div><img src="'.$images.'" alt="xxx" />This is the lightbox!!!</div>';

      echo "<b>$id</b><br><a href=\"show.php?id=$id\">Riferimento</a><br>Rif: " . $riferimenti . "<br>titolo: " . $titolo . "<br>tipotransazione: " . $tipotransazione . "<br>tipoproprieta: " . $tipoproprieta . "<br>regione: " . $regione . "<br>città: " . $citta . "<br>prezzo: " . $prezzo . "<br>spazivivibili: " . $spazivivibili . "<br>terrenoprivato: " . $terrenoprivato . "<br>condizioniproprieta: " . $condizioniproprieta . "<br>piano: " . $piano . "<br>numeropiani: " . $numeropiani . "<br>numerostanze: " . $numerostanze . "<br>numerocamereletto: " . $numerocamereletto . "<br>numerobagni: " . $numerobagni . "<br>numeroantibagni: " . $numeroantibagni . "<br>tipologiariscaldamento: " . $tipologiariscaldamento . "<br>cucina: " . $cucina . "<br>ascensore: " . $ascensore . "<br>postoauto: " . $postoauto . "<br>balconeterrazzo: " . $balconeterrazzo . "<br>ipe: " . $ipe . "<br>classeenergetica: " . $classeenergetica . "<br>spesecondominiali: " . $spesecondominiali . "<br>comforts: " . $comforts . "<br>descrizione: " . $descrizione . "<br>linkvideo: " . $linkvideo . "<br>
     <a href=\"cancella.php?id=$id\">Cancella</a> |
     <a href=\"modifica.php?id=$id\">Modifica</a>
     <hr>";
    }
  }

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split data to multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518325/split-data-to-multiple-columns)

Comment: could you please post expected output

Comment: Thanks for your answer, read my edit, please

Comment: ok, I edited my question and I post a screen on my ideal output. Thanks

Comment: Look for a tutorial on `HTML Tables`

Comment: I know I can divide manually data, but I have a lots of data to show, so I hoped to do it simply by code

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they will be removed from PHP in future versions and your code will stop working then. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo ('<table width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr>');
  include 'config.php';
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM immobili"; //WHERE citta='pincopalla'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
  if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $id = stripslashes($fetch['id']);
      $riferimenti = stripslashes($fetch['riferimenti']);
      $titolo = stripslashes($fetch['titolo']);
      $tipotransazione = stripslashes($fetch['tipotransazione']);
      $tipoproprieta = stripslashes($fetch['tipoproprieta']);
      $regione = stripslashes($fetch['regione']);
      $citta = stripslashes($fetch['citta']);
      $prezzo = stripslashes($fetch['prezzo']);
      $spazivivibili = stripslashes($fetch['spazivivibili']);
      $terrenoprivato = stripslashes($fetch['terrenoprivato']);
      $condizioniproprieta = stripslashes($fetch['condizioniproprieta']);
      $piano = stripslashes($fetch['piano']);
      $numeropiani = stripslashes($fetch['numeropiani']);
      $numerostanze = stripslashes($fetch['numerostanze']);
      $numerocamereletto = stripslashes($fetch['numerocamereletto']);
      $numerobagni = stripslashes($fetch['numerobagni']);
      $numeroantibagni = stripslashes($fetch['numeroantibagni']);
      $tipologiariscaldamento = stripslashes($fetch['tipologiariscaldamento']);
      $cucina = stripslashes($fetch['cucina']);
      $ascensore = stripslashes($fetch['ascensore']);
      $postoauto = stripslashes($fetch['postoauto']);
      $balconeterrazzo = stripslashes($fetch['balconeterrazzo']);
      $ipe = stripslashes($fetch['ipe']);
      $classeenergetica = stripslashes($fetch['classeenergetica']);
      $spesecondominiali = stripslashes($fetch['spesecondominiali']);
      $comforts = stripslashes($fetch['comforts']);
      $linkvideo = stripslashes($fetch['linkvideo']);
  $descrizione = stripslashes($fetch['descrizione']);
      $data = date("d-m-Y", $fetch['str_data']);
      ?>
 <?php

 $dirname = "images/".$citta;
$images = $dirname.$linkvideo;



echo('<th scope="col"><a href="#" class="lightbox"><img src="'.$images.'" /></a></th>');// row 1

echo('<th scope="col"><div class="backdrop"></div><div class="box"><div class="close">x</div><img src="'.$images.'" alt="xxx" />This is the lightbox!!!</div></th>');// row2

echo('<th scope="col"><b>'.$id.'</b><br><a href=\"show.php?id='.$id.'\">Riferimento</a><br>Rif: "'.$riferimenti.'"<br>titolo: "'.$titolo.'"<br>tipotransazione: "'.$tipotransazione.'"<br>tipoproprieta: "'.$tipoproprieta.'"<br>regione: " . $regione . "<br>città: " . $citta . "<br>prezzo: " . $prezzo . "<br>spazivivibili: " .$spazivivibili . "<br>terrenoprivato: " . $terrenoprivato . "<br>condizioniproprieta: " . $condizioniproprieta . "<br>piano: " . $piano . "<br>numeropiani: " . $numeropiani . "<br>numerostanze: " . $numerostanze . "<br>numerocamereletto: " . $numerocamereletto . "<br>numerobagni: " . $numerobagni . "<br>numeroantibagni: " . $numeroantibagni . "<br>tipologiariscaldamento: " . $tipologiariscaldamento . "<br>cucina: " . $cucina . "<br>ascensore: " . $ascensore . "<br>postoauto: " . $postoauto . "<br>balconeterrazzo: " . $balconeterrazzo . "<br>ipe: " . $ipe . "<br>classeenergetica: " . $classeenergetica . "<br>spesecondominiali: " . $spesecondominiali . "<br>comforts: " . $comforts . "<br>descrizione: " . $descrizione . "<br>linkvideo: " . $linkvideo . "<br>
     <a href=\"cancella.php?id=$id\">Cancella</a> |
     <a href=\"modifica.php?id=$id\">Modifica</a>
     <hr></th>'); // row 3


    }
  }
echo ('</tr></tbody></table>');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's almost perfect, but it shows all in one row, I need to show them in just 3 columns. Can you see my initial post where I put a screen of my desired output? thank you :)

Comment: Hi, sorry if I answer after 1 month but I had some personal problem...anyway, I checked your answer and, for the first, I corrected something, check it:

Answer (score 0):

try the below code.i write it only for image .

```
<?php

include 'config.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM immobili"; //WHERE citta='pincopalla'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
$count= mysql_num_rows($result);$i=0;
echo '<table width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr>';
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $id = stripslashes($fetch['id']);
  $riferimenti = stripslashes($fetch['riferimenti']);
  $titolo = stripslashes($fetch['titolo']);
  $tipotransazione = stripslashes($fetch['tipotransazione']);
  $tipoproprieta = stripslashes($fetch['tipoproprieta']);
  $regione = stripslashes($fetch['regione']);
  $citta = stripslashes($fetch['citta']);
  $prezzo = stripslashes($fetch['prezzo']);
  $spazivivibili = stripslashes($fetch['spazivivibili']);
  $terrenoprivato = stripslashes($fetch['terrenoprivato']);
  $condizioniproprieta = stripslashes($fetch['condizioniproprieta']);
  $piano = stripslashes($fetch['piano']);
  $numeropiani = stripslashes($fetch['numeropiani']);
  $numerostanze = stripslashes($fetch['numerostanze']);
  $numerocamereletto = stripslashes($fetch['numerocamereletto']);
  $numerobagni = stripslashes($fetch['numerobagni']);
  $numeroantibagni = stripslashes($fetch['numeroantibagni']);
  $tipologiariscaldamento = stripslashes($fetch['tipologiariscaldamento']);
  $cucina = stripslashes($fetch['cucina']);
  $ascensore = stripslashes($fetch['ascensore']);
  $postoauto = stripslashes($fetch['postoauto']);
  $balconeterrazzo = stripslashes($fetch['balconeterrazzo']);
  $ipe = stripslashes($fetch['ipe']);
  $classeenergetica = stripslashes($fetch['classeenergetica']);
  $spesecondominiali = stripslashes($fetch['spesecondominiali']);
  $comforts = stripslashes($fetch['comforts']);
  $linkvideo = stripslashes($fetch['linkvideo']);
  $descrizione = stripslashes($fetch['descrizione']);
  $data = date("d-m-Y", $fetch['str_data']);

  if($i%3==0){
     echo "</tr><tr>"
   }
   $dirname = "images/".$citta;
   $images = $dirname.$linkvideo;

    echo '<td scope="col"><a href="#" class="lightbox"><img src="'.$images.'" /></a><br /><div class="backdrop"></div><div class="box"><div class="close">x</div><img src="'.$images.'" alt="xxx" />This is the lightbox!!!</div></td>';

   $i++;}
 }
 echo "</tr></tbody></table>";
  ?>
```

Comment: updated  answer check once now...it is for 3 coloumns only

Comment: sorry but can you show me a complete example for the others datas? because in this way it isn't working... Thank you!

Comment: are u asking about other fields

Answer (score 0):

@paisapimp

Hi, sorry if I answer after 1 month but I had some personal problem...anyway, I checked your answer and, for the first, I corrected something, check it:

```
`enter code here`

<?php
    echo ('<table width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr>');
     include 'config.php';
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM immobili"; //WHERE citta='pincopalla'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
  if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $id = stripslashes($fetch['id']);
      $riferimenti = stripslashes($fetch['riferimenti']);
      $titolo = stripslashes($fetch['titolo']);
      $tipotransazione = stripslashes($fetch['tipotransazione']);
      $tipoproprieta = stripslashes($fetch['tipoproprieta']);
      $regione = stripslashes($fetch['regione']);
      $citta = stripslashes($fetch['citta']);
      $prezzo = stripslashes($fetch['prezzo']);
      $spazivivibili = stripslashes($fetch['spazivivibili']);
      $terrenoprivato = stripslashes($fetch['terrenoprivato']);
      $condizioniproprieta = stripslashes($fetch['condizioniproprieta']);
      $piano = stripslashes($fetch['piano']);
      $numeropiani = stripslashes($fetch['numeropiani']);
      $numerostanze = stripslashes($fetch['numerostanze']);
      $numerocamereletto = stripslashes($fetch['numerocamereletto']);
      $numerobagni = stripslashes($fetch['numerobagni']);
      $numeroantibagni = stripslashes($fetch['numeroantibagni']);
      $tipologiariscaldamento = stripslashes($fetch['tipologiariscaldamento']);
      $cucina = stripslashes($fetch['cucina']);
      $ascensore = stripslashes($fetch['ascensore']);
      $postoauto = stripslashes($fetch['postoauto']);
      $balconeterrazzo = stripslashes($fetch['balconeterrazzo']);
      $ipe = stripslashes($fetch['ipe']);
      $classeenergetica = stripslashes($fetch['classeenergetica']);
      $spesecondominiali = stripslashes($fetch['spesecondominiali']);
      $comforts = stripslashes($fetch['comforts']);
      $linkvideo = stripslashes($fetch['linkvideo']);
  $descrizione = stripslashes($fetch['descrizione']);
      $data = date("d-m-Y", $fetch['str_data']);
      ?>
 <?php

 $dirname = "images/".$citta;
$images = $dirname.$linkvideo;



echo('<th scope="col"><b>'.$id.'</b><br><a href=\"show.php?id='.$id.'\">Riferimento</a><br>Rif: "'.$riferimenti.'"<br>titolo: "'.$titolo.'"<br>tipotransazione: "'.$tipotransazione.'"<br>tipoproprieta: "'.$tipoproprieta.'"<br>
     <a href=\"cancella.php?id=$id\">Cancella</a> |
     <a href=\"modifica.php?id=$id\">Modifica</a>
     <hr></th>');// row 1




    }
  }
echo ('</tr></tbody></table>');
?>
```

From this code I need to truncate after 3 columns and restart in a second row, for example check this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjzwJ.jpg)

I hope you can understand me now :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> You can make table view by this way:-
>
> You can add other fiels by adding title in first `<tr>` and value in 2nd `<tr>`;

I have added six columns and their values in given table.

```
<table border='2'>
<tr>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Rif</th>
    <th>titolo</th>
    <th>tipotransazione</th>
    <th>tipoproprieta</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
</tr>

<?php
 while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $id = stripslashes($fetch['id']);
      $riferimenti = stripslashes($fetch['riferimenti']);
      $titolo = stripslashes($fetch['titolo']);
      $tipotransazione = stripslashes($fetch['tipotransazione']);
      $tipoproprieta = stripslashes($fetch['tipoproprieta']);
      $regione = stripslashes($fetch['regione']);
      $citta = stripslashes($fetch['citta']);
      $prezzo = stripslashes($fetch['prezzo']);
      $spazivivibili = stripslashes($fetch['spazivivibili']);
      $terrenoprivato = stripslashes($fetch['terrenoprivato']);
      $condizioniproprieta = stripslashes($fetch['condizioniproprieta']);
      $piano = stripslashes($fetch['piano']);
      $numeropiani = stripslashes($fetch['numeropiani']);
      $numerostanze = stripslashes($fetch['numerostanze']);
      $numerocamereletto = stripslashes($fetch['numerocamereletto']);
      $numerobagni = stripslashes($fetch['numerobagni']);
      $numeroantibagni = stripslashes($fetch['numeroantibagni']);
      $tipologiariscaldamento = stripslashes($fetch['tipologiariscaldamento']);
      $cucina = stripslashes($fetch['cucina']);
      $ascensore = stripslashes($fetch['ascensore']);
      $postoauto = stripslashes($fetch['postoauto']);
      $balconeterrazzo = stripslashes($fetch['balconeterrazzo']);
      $ipe = stripslashes($fetch['ipe']);
      $classeenergetica = stripslashes($fetch['classeenergetica']);
      $spesecondominiali = stripslashes($fetch['spesecondominiali']);
      $comforts = stripslashes($fetch['comforts']);
      $linkvideo = stripslashes($fetch['linkvideo']);
      $descrizione = stripslashes($fetch['descrizione']);
      $data = date("d-m-Y", $fetch['str_data']);

      $dirname = "images/".$citta;
      $images = $dirname.$linkvideo;    
      ?>    


            <tr>
                <td><a href="#" class="lightbox"><img src="'.$images.'" /></a><br />
                    <div class="backdrop"></div><div class="box"><div class="close">x</div><img src="'.$images.'" alt="xxx" />This is the lightbox!!!</div>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $riferimenti ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $titolo ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $tipotransazione ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $regione ?></td>
                <td><a href="cancella.php?id=$id">Cancella</a> |
                     <a href="modifica.php?id=$id">Modifica</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

    }

</table>
```